# Using Less, can I not output a base class for extend?

Tags: less

Using [Less](http://lesscss.org/), I can not output a mixin class by putting parens after the class name

```
.my-mixin()
{
  color: red;
}
```

That way it must be used as a mixin and a developer can't accidentally use it as a class like `<div class="my-mixin">something</div>`.

If I do something similar with extend instead:

```
.my-base
{
    color: red;
}

.my-class:extend(.my-base)
{
    background-color: grey;
}
```

The generated CSS is:

```
.my-base, .my-class
{
    color: red;
}

.my-class
{
    background-color: grey;
}
```

How can I change my Less so that the `.my-base` class isn't output so that it can't be accidentally used?

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible with `:extend`. Mixins that are not output cannot be extended (unless somebody comes up with some complex hack - which I wouldn't recommend anyway). Using a mixin call would be the only way (and then maybe some compressor to group selectors).

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045192. Though personally I'd suggest to not rely on any hacks like there but just to stress the auxiliary meaning of the base classes via their names (e.g. `.my-base__` or whatever).